# Git Glob syntax: ignoring files everywhere or in a specific folder

Tags: git, gitignore, glob

I would like to exclude `.DS_Store` tracking from myfolder and **all subfolders**. I also want to exclude a `.project` file from myfolder (but **not** from its **subfolders**).

What should I write in .gitignore (situated in myfolder)?

```
.DS_Store # or *.DS_Store ? I mean, is the asterisk necessary?
./.project # is this syntax correct?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
.DS_Store
/.project
```

When you a provide a path to .gitignore, it applies it based on where the .gitignore file is (a chroot, if you will).  So the / on the second line means only ignore the `myfolder/.project` file.